# Error on install Hugo academic blogdown on github pages

Tags: github-pages, hugo, blogdown

I've been trying to create a personal site using blogdown and the academic template:

`blogdown::new_site(theme = "gcushen/hugo-academic")`

However when I try to attach the site to github pages I get the error:

```
our site is having problems building: The variable {{2\left( {x + 4} on line 58 in content/slides/example-slides.md was not properly closed with }}. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-tag-not-properly-terminated/.
```

It looked properly terminated...but regardless, I've tried to delete the file but alas the same error comes up even with its removal.

The site is `https://github.com/sebastiz/SebastianZekiCV/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to publish a user site via github pages either:

1) the name of the repository must be exactly .github.io
In this case, the pages will be served from the HEAD of your master branch (or the gh-pages branch - your choice). The root of the repository is the root of the site.

2) the name of the repository can be anything. In this case, it will served from the master branch, but from the /docs directory.

In either case, github pages will run Jekyll. The only way to stop it is to have only "static" files - e.g. CSS, html pages, images, etc.

What you can do is create two repositories - one will be your source; the other will be the actual pages served. You can use `hugo -d <path>` to tell hugo to build its output in the root of the clone for the "output" repository.

Further reading:

[github pages help configuring source](https://help.github.com/articles/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-github-pages/)

[hugo command reference](https://gohugo.io/commands/hugo/)

Answer (score 1):

For this problem, the ideal solution which is suggested is to create separate repositories for code and static content. However, the error can be solved by disabling Jekyll to run.

Create a file called `.nojekyll` at the root of your repository.

You can then go ahead and choose `publishDir = "docs"` and server from the `docs/` directory in the master branch.